# How to Change Date Format in .net RDLC Report?

Tags: sql, dataset, rdlc, datetime-format

I need to set my date column as **01-Jan-2013**, what is the format to acheieve this in rdlc?

I have given

```
=CDate(Fields!IssuingDate.Value).ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

its not working correctly. Any one post me the format for **02-Jul-2013**.

Answer (score 29):

Use this you will get your output

```
=CDate(Fields!IssuingDate.Value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 22):

**Possibility 1:**

I think the correct format string is `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` (*uppercase M*, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx))

And I would use `Format(Fields!IssuingDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")`instead of `ToString()`

**Possibility 2:**

Just use `Fields!IssuingDate.Value` as Expression of your TextBox and set the `Format` property of the TextBox to `dd-MMM-yyyy`

Answer (score 11):

Date formats can also be changed by right clicking the field in the RDLC report (whose format we want to change) and:

1. choose "Text box properties"
2. then choose the option "Number"
3. then choose one of the multiple "Date" options, or specify a Custom [formatting option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the `Expression` property, set the following format and it will work fine:

```
=Format(Cdate(Fields!InvoiceDate.Value),"yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any formatting function like Format(). 
Instead right click on the text box and select Text Box Properties...
And then select Number from left column and set your desire format like in Excel.

You can many other properties like Alignment, Fill and Action.

Comment: In my case, I need to round to 2 decimals and it was rounding 175.89 to 175.9. I removed Round() and apply the format like mentioned above and get the desired result 175.90

Answer (score 1):

Check the datatype in XSD is `System.DateTimeOffset`, I couldn't get any formatting working without changing the type to `System.DateTime` .

[image]
Covert datetimeoffset to datetime from the select query:

```
SELECT 
A,
B,
CONVERT(datetime2, MyTable.DateTimeOffsetField, 1) AS DateTimeField
FROM MyTable
```

After changing the type to DateTime all the formatting started working

Eg: `=Format(Fields!DateTimeField.Vaule, "dd-mmm-yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful

```
= CDate(Fields!Date.Value).ToString("dd-MMM.-yyyy" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CDate(Fields!IssuingDate.Value).ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Change it as follows it will work definitely:

`ToString` should be `toString` and `mmm` should be `MMM`, so you'll have:

```
CDate(Fields!IssuingDate.Value).toString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, too (and doesn't fail when DateValue.Value is null):

```
=String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", Fields!DateValue.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your rdlc as XML and just use Now(), the same as DateTime.Now, and Format.

```
<Value>="Date: " &amp; Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</Value>
```

Result in file "Date: 22/08/2019 10:20"

Answer (score 0):

RDLC 2022
=CDate(Fields!DateField.Value).toShortDateString();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).