# Formatting Date in RDLC removes Date

Tags: vb.net, datetime, rdlc

I want to pass the date in the query string throw the action of a column in rdlc. when I use `ReportItems!txt_date.Value` it only passes the time portion of the date because of the "/" I believe.

If I add a column and simply set its expression to `ReportItems!txt_date.Value` The date shows up fine as 1/1/0001 : 12:00:00 AM.

As soon as I try to format it with something like `=Replace(ReportItems!txt_Date.Value,"/","-")` the entire date is removed and I am left with just 12:00:00 AM.

I even tried writing a custom function in the RDLC code, and oddly all it does is accept the date as a string parameter and return it. This too strips out the date and leaves just 12:00:00 AM even though I have done nothing to the string.

Expression:

```
=Code.FormatDate(ReportItems!txt_Date.Value)
```

Report Code

```
Public Function FormatDate (ByVal Value As String) As String

Return Value
End Function
```

What is the correct way to do this. In the end, I just want to be able to send date in my query string like so;

```
=Parameters!QueryParam.Value & ReportItems!txt_ChkNo.Value & "&Date?=" & ReportItems!txt_Date.Value
```

But for some reason it only sends the time portion (12:00:00AM)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17802399/1070452 they are all using ToStrind to format a Date; your looks to be converting the date to string.

Comment: @Plutonix That fixed my issue! If you put that as answer I can mark as correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just upvote the answers in the link which helped