# Display Date and time instead of only date?

Tags: c#, mysql, rdlc

I have a column named date of data type date in database. I am inserting data using `CURDATE()`. But when I retrieve data instead of showing only date it also showing time [image]. I am using ***MySQL*** databse and ***C#*** language. How to get only date not time. I retrieve data in rdlc report.

Comment: It is not clear what the display context is. More details on the problem are needed for a relevant solution to be recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to show the date in short date format:

```
yourDate.ToString("d")
```

You can also have your own format, for example this:

```
yourDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

MSDN has a nice list of possible date formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

To do this in a RDLC report, take a look at the following link: [How to Change Date Format in .net RDLC Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802399/how-to-change-date-format-in-net-rdlc-report)

Comment: how to do it in report. I am getting report data through query builder

Comment: this is for built in date option in report. not for my case as I am getting already saved value.

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh I think it would be better to update the post to include more detail on how you're retrieving the data.

Comment: thank you sir. i have tried one solution from the link you have shared and my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the date in your current culture you can use `ToShortDateString()` method detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) in the docs.

```
string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Date and time you can use

```
YourDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

In database you also select data type is Date and Time
```